# Taylor series of a square matrix

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, matrices, taylor-expansion

Let $A$ be a constant square matrix, $\Delta t$ is a scalar. I would imagine a taylor series of its exponential like this:

$$e ^{A\,\Delta t} = I + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(A\,\Delta t)^n}{n!} $$

Now if I want to approximate as a first order term only:
$e ^{A\,\Delta t} = I + A\,\Delta t$, I have to say that $\frac{(A\,\Delta t)^2}{2!}$ should be small. But $A$ is not a number but a matrix. What matrix norm should I use to say that $\frac{(A\,\Delta t)^2}{2!}$ is small?

Comment: All norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent, so you may choose any one you like.

Comment: I've used this type of expansion for some physics problems, and it always involves multiplying with a column vector on the right, and a row vector on the left. So in your expansion you would get something like $v A\Delta t v^T$. I would just use the $\max(|A_{i,j}\Delta t|)$ as my norm

Comment: Whatever norm you use, $\|A (\Delta t)\|^2 \le (\Delta t)^2 \| A\\^2$, so the smallness comes from $\Delta t$.

Comment: @John Ma do you mean $||A(\Delta t)||^2 \leq (\Delta t)^2||A||$? why?

Comment: @kww $\Delta t$ is a scalar, and it is the definition of a norm that $\|cx\| = |c| \|x\|$ for all $x$ and for all scalar $c$.